# How to create Sharing Social Media without Plugin and Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a problem in my site.I tried making a site using html, css and little bit javascript. and I wanna create a sharing social button for every article that I posted.I want the share button get the url, meta keyword and meta description in every page.. how to do that.I tried using sharethis plugin . but I don't use it anymore. because it make my site slowly. hope someone understand and can do that. facebook, twiiter and google+. thanks! #edit my question grammar.

```
<title>How to make Great Donuts</title> <meta description="Making a great donuts for spend your time />
```

facebook button share ------> when user click, it will directed in facebook and display the Title tag as a header and Meta description for the Content.

Comment: why don't you to look at developers facebook it's already existing right there

Comment: but it will make us manually edit the link to share right? i want a automatically get the post article. is that possible? thanks!

Comment: nope, it will automatically get the post where you in

Answer (score 0):

Facebook, Twitter and other social media sites have procedures one can easily follow to integrate social sharing on posts, etc.

For facebook, see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

You can google there rest you wish to implement

Comment: but it will make us manually edit the link to share right? i want a automatically get the post article. is that possible? thanks!

Comment: No, you have to define a logic that makes it automatic. Say on the page where you display your posts, you can include the button as one of your database results and add the link and title to it. That way, for all pages, it's dynamically updated and different for each post. Initial setup may be a hassle but once you get a hang of it, you're golden